# use variables of one class in another class Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
# cartmodel

    `class CartModel extends ChangeNotifier {
      // list of items on sale
      final List _shopItems = const [
        // [ itemName, itemPrice, imagePath, color ]
        ["Avocado", "4", "assets/images/avocado.png", Colors.green],
        ["Banana", "2", "assets/images/banana.png", Colors.yellow],
        ["pollo", "12", "assets/images/chicken.png", Colors.brown],
        ["acqua", "1", "assets/images/water.png", Colors.blue],
        ["mela", "3", "assets/images/mela.png", Colors.red],
        ["broccoli", "3", "assets/images/broccoli.png", Colors.brown],
      ];
    
      final List _faidate = const [
        ["Avocado", "14000", "assets/images/avocado.png", Colors.orange],
        ["Banana", "2", "assets/images/banana.png", Colors.blueGrey],
        ["pollo", "12", "assets/images/chicken.png", Colors.red],
        ["acqua", "1", "assets/images/water.png", Colors.blue],
      ];
    
      // list of cart items
      final List _cartItems = [];
    
      get faidate => _faidate;
    
      get cartItems => _cartItems;
    
      get shopItems => _shopItems;
      // add item to cart
      void addItemToCart(int index) {
        _cartItems.add(_shopItems[index]);
        notifyListeners();
      }
    
      // remove item from cart
      void removeItemFromCart(int index) {
        _cartItems.removeAt(index);
        notifyListeners();
      }
    
      // calculate total price
      String calculateTotal() {
        double totalPrice = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
          totalPrice += double.parse(cartItems[i][1].toString());
        }
        return totalPrice.toStringAsFixed(2);
      }
    }`
```

## cartpage

```
`class CartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  CartPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Device.screenType == ScreenType.tablet;
    return Container(
      width: 100.w,
      height: 90.5.h,
      child: Container(
        width: 100.w,
        height: 20.5.h,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: Colors.grey[800],
            ),
          ),
          body: Consumer<CartModel>(
            builder: (context, value, child) {
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  // Let's order fresh items for you
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Cart",
                      style: GoogleFonts.notoSerif(
                        fontSize: 36,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  // list view of cart
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: (value.cartItems.length),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                              child: ListTile(
                                leading: Image.asset(
                                  value.cartItems[index][2],
                                  height: 36,
                                ),
                                title: Text(
                                  value.cartItems[index][0],
                                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Text(
                                  '\points ' + value.cartItems[index][1],
                                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                ),
                                trailing: IconButton(
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                                  onPressed: () => Provider.of<CartModel>(
                                          context,
                                          listen: false)
                                      .removeItemFromCart(index),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  // total amount + pay now

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          color: Colors.blueGrey[900]),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'total price',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[200]),
                              ),

                              const SizedBox(height: 8),
                              // total price
                              Text(
                                '\Points ${value.calculateTotal()}',
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),

                          // pay now
                          Container(
                          
                            ), 
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () {},
                                    child: const Text('order now')),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`

```
# points page

`class points extends StatefulWidget {

  points({Key? key,}) :super(key: key);
  _pointsState createState() => _pointsState();

 } 


class _pointsState extends State<points> {
  int _points = 0;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadPunti();
  }

  _loadPunti() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _points = (prefs.getInt('points') ?? 0);
    });
  }

  _savePunti() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('xxxx').add({
      'Points': _points,
    });
 
  }
other code...
```

hi all, I was looking for a solution for this test of a flutter shopping app and I'm having problems in being able to use the "points" variable in the cart page to be able to confirm a purchase on the "onpressed" in the cartpage, I also attached the cartmodel like this to be able to verify. Thank you all

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i put the code in the code section if you know how to use "_points" in the cartpage that would be great, Thanks